# SpriteKit - minimize quadcount

Tags: ios, performance, debugging, sprite-kit

I've been trying to teach myself SpriteKit and jumped into Raywenderlich's tutorials which said that QuadCount should be minimized for a better performance. I turned on showQuadCount, showDrawCount, showNodeCount for debugging. However, I saw quadcount is always equals to node count. Anyone can help me  explain in a simple way what quadcount really is and give me an example on that quadcount is different from nodecount. (I did search google but I can not understand, so please do not give me a link without explaination). Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you add a link to what you have been reading. Do you actually have a performance issue? Sure the quad count should be as minimal as possible but if you need to draw 10 quads you can only do it by drawing 10 quads, you may only gain in cases where there is lots of overlapping or the quads are not even visible on the screen.

Comment: Sorry Matic, It's the book that my company bought, so I dont have the link.

Answer (score 4):

Every node that draws something draws a quad (two triangles).

So only `SKNode` nodes which don't draw anything will not increase the quad count.

Also, quad count nearly isn't everything. It's more important to support Sprite Kit's internal batching by using texture atlases, and avoiding child nodes that use different texture atlas than their parent, otherwise this would interrupt batching.

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D. I still do not understand the real meaning of quadCount but Today at least I found one case on which quadcount is different from nodecount. I used core graphics to draw a circle and create SKShapeNode with that circle. The nodecount = 1 but the quadcount is > 100.

Comment: A SKShapeNode circle will be made of lots of triangles to give it an circular shape